# Send invitation to Facebook and Google+ Friends

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, google-plus

I want to allow to user to send invitation for their Facebook and Google+ friends.

For the moment I have two solutions

1. Share he invitation in the user's wall
2. Send the invitation using the Facebook or Google+ mail

What is the best manner to do this ? Does anyone have a solution better than the two above solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you want to do, use the Graph API. It's pretty simple, just reference the Publish section at this URL
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You'll need some prework in your app to allow your users to authenticate and to authorize your app to post on behalf of them. It's straightforward though.

If you're looking for a more cutting edge way to spread your app on Facebook, "Social App Discovery" is the most up to date way to do this. You'll be able to have links appear right on walls that take users either to your app if they have it installed, or to the app store to download it (all handled by Facebook). Read about it here
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the Google+ interactive posts with the "INVITE" call-to-action label.

- [Feature overview](https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts)
- [Sharing interactive posts on iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#adding_interactive_posts)